# AWS Lambda C# .net core runtime to use RDS Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, amazon-rds

I have a Lambda function written in c# .net core 3.1 runtime. In which I am using MySQL for some DB-related stuff. I want to use RDS Proxy on this function (will apply to other functions later) as my application is making too many connections. I've searched on the internet about how to apply RDS Proxy in code level on MySQL client in c# (.NEt core 3.1 runtime) but couldn't find anything helpful. I'll really appreciate it if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create & add database proxy for Lambda. Once created, you'll get the endpoint which you can use to connect to database like you normally use. The magic in that proxy endpoint URL and transparent to us.

Reference to documentation
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: I have done it but the problem is that I am not able to connect to RDS Instance in c# code while interacting with the database. I have seen the given link and successfully created RDS Proxy and applied it to a test function but when it comes to the coding part I am only seeing the javascript code samples but In my case i am using c# with mysql client to connect to rds my SQL DB instance. I tried to use the proxy endpoint in my connection string but it is not working.

Comment: Please share more details as to what is not working. Share the code you're using and exact error you're getting.

Comment: @JahanAhmedAbbasi Create a new question